# Trying to connect to a remote unix 64bit machine with GUI jProfiler by a windows7 64bit machine but the client GUI doesnt answer

Tags: java, tomcat, jprofiler

I am trying to connect to a remote unix 64bit machine with GUI jProfiler by a windows7 64bit machine but the client GUI doesnt answer..

I've already set the java opts in my startup_jprofiler.sh

```
-agentpath:/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=9988,nowait
```

and when my server starts it outputs this jprofiler log

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 36
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
JProfiler> Listening on port: 9988.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Hotspot compiler enabled
```

everything seems to be fine but my gui client (on windows7) doesnt connects to the remote machine..

and yes I have opened the 9988 port with a iptables rule (as a matter of fact i've even fully disabled iptables and it doesnt worked)

Comment: Can you telnet from the Windows machine to the Unix box on port 9988 ? This is a good way to check whether or not the problem is network related.

Comment: i have already done that.. when I telnet the port i got no answer but the port is completely open.. is the jprofiler who doesnt answer

Comment: And can you telnet from the Unix host to itself on port 9988 ?

Comment: What does `netstat -a | grep 9988` say on the Unix machine?

Comment: sais that there is a process LISTEN(ing) on this port..

Comment: @DavidLevesque when i telnet on localhost at 9988 i get connected successfully.. =\

Comment: Is it possible that there is another firewall between the two machines ? What is your network configuration ?

Comment: no @DavidLevesque, I am certified of it